# Python object of arrays count number of similar array value occurrences

Tags: python, list

Apologies for the wording of this question. I have the beneath list containing sub-objects that also contains key, value pairs.

```
l = [{'melissa': ["power"]}, {'Linda': ["power", "a"]}, {'Rachel': ["power", "document"]}]
```

This is my current solution that counts the amount of occurrences of strings in each objects list as expected:

```
cnt  = {}
for i in l:
    for x in i.values():
        for j in x:
            if j not in cnt:
                cnt[j] = 1
            else:
                cnt[j] += 1
final = list(map(list, cnt.items()))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
final = [['power', 3], ['a', 1], ['document', 1]]
```

Is there a better/more succinct method of doing this?

I would still like the output to be a list of sub-lists.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [
    {"melissa": ["power"]},
    {"Linda": ["power", "a"]},
    {"Rachel": ["power", "document"]},
]

out = Counter(i for d in l for lst in d.values() for i in lst)
out = list(map(list, out.items()))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['power', 3], ['a', 1], ['document', 1]]
```

Comment: Was thinking of this too :D

Comment: This is perfect, I was thinking of making use of the `Counter` import but am not overly familiar with it. Thanks.